# How do I locate a 16 digit string in a freetext field in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to formulate a solution for a report I generate daily.  There is a freetext field which must be selected but there is a potential for a 16 digit CC number to appear.  I need to find a way to locate and exclude these.  Any ideas?

Comment: Will the 16 digits be guaranteed consecutive or might they have spaces? What about American Express cards that have 15 digits? Or Diner's club cards with 14? The most robust way would be to use regex and something like https://regular-expressions.mobi/creditcard.html?wlr=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `patindex()`:

```
select patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', col)
```

This give you the offset where the pattern starts.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE     @CCNumber   varchar(20) =   '1234 5678 9012 3456'   -- CC Number
DECLARE     @Table      TABLE   (FreeTextField varchar(max))    -- Sample Table with one FreeTextField
INSERT INTO @Table      VALUES
            ('This is a text without any CC number')
        ,   ('This a text with the CC number 1234 5678 9012 3456')
        ,   ('This another text without any CC number')
        ,   ('This another text with the CC number 1234 5678 9012 3456')

-- The following script will show only rows without the CC Number
SELECT  FreeTextField
FROM    @Table
WHERE CHARINDEX(@CCNumber, FreeTextField) = 0

-- If you want to show all rows, but mask the CC Number then do the following
DECLARE @MaskCCNumber varchar(20) = '#### #### #### ####'

SELECT  FreeTextField =  REPLACE(FreeTextField, @CCNumber, @MaskCCNumber)
FROM    @Table
```